# Why webmatrix create mvcforum site as website and not web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webmatrix

> I created web app of mvcforum with webmatrix and now when i create
>   again its website and not soloution project how i can create web
>   soloution project of mvcforum with webmatrix?

Comment: VS community express is free to download and is almost fully featured IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

WebMatrix doesn't support the Web Application project type. Therefore it is not the correct tool for ASP.NET MVC development. You should use Visual Studio instead. The Community edition is free for single users and includes the same feature set as the Developer version (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx).